# Displaying a specific Document's field in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I m very new to firestore. So i have been trying to get my data back from firestore, but only a single field which is the `userName` field. However, I have no idea how to access just a single field inside a document.

My Result now :

> flutter: Document data: {age: 50, email: bigboi@gmail.com, userName: Nicolo Big Boi}

The code :

```
Future getUserData() async {
    return userCollection
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
  }
```

But this is what I want :

```
flutter: Document data: { userName: Nicolo Big Boi}
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you try `print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()["userName"]}')`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ,thank you sir. I tried that piece of code, and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear. I wrote it up as a quick answer below too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a specific field of the `DocumentSnapshot` you can use:

```
print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()["userName"]}')
```